# How to capture MouseUp event outside the WPF window?

Tags: wpf

The subject is all in the title. Sorry if it's a duplicate, I really couldn't find anything on SO.

Comment: See this [`link`](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/362352/Csharp-Mouse-Event-outside-the-Form), it refers to the `WinForms`, but for WPF will be the same. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732070/how-can-i-capture-mouse-events-that-occur-outside-of-a-wpf-window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, many thanks to Anatoliy Nikolaev for steering me in the right direction! That [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) helped me much and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255771/692829) was useful to make code from the article work. This is what I have now:

```
internal static class MouseHook
{
    private delegate int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private static int _mouseHookHandle;
    private static HookProc _mouseDelegate;

    private static event MouseUpEventHandler MouseUp;
    public static event MouseUpEventHandler OnMouseUp
    {
        add
        {
            Subscribe();
            MouseUp += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            MouseUp -= value;
            Unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    private static void Unsubscribe()
    {
        if (_mouseHookHandle != 0)
        {
            int result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(_mouseHookHandle);
            _mouseHookHandle = 0;
            _mouseDelegate = null;
            if (result == 0)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Subscribe()
    {
        if (_mouseHookHandle == 0)
        {
            _mouseDelegate = MouseHookProc;
            _mouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,
                _mouseDelegate,
                GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName),
                0);
            if (_mouseHookHandle == 0)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int MouseHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT mouseHookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
            {
                if (MouseUp != null)
                {
                    MouseUp.Invoke(null, new Point(mouseHookStruct.pt.x, mouseHookStruct.pt.y));
                }
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_mouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }     

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
       CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string name); 
}

public delegate void MouseUpEventHandler(object sender, Point p);
```

And using it is pretty simple:

```
MouseHook.OnMouseUp += MouseHookMouseUp;
```

Comment: i haven't actually checked if this works , but just by the look of it +1 .

i'll let you know , this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: this works great , do you know of a way to cancel to the message processing after MouseHookProc , lets say i have a winform control 
and i wan't to revert click events from it , WM_LBUTTONDOWN i catch the message process and in some condition i would like it to stop there , and the control would not receive the mouse input.

Comment: @eran otzap If I understand you correctly, if you are using the code from my answer you need to unsubscribe:  `MouseHook.OnMouseUp -= MouseHookMouseUp`. To stop control receiving mouse input I guess, you'll need to use a more "traditional" event handler like `control.MouseUp+=control_MouseUp` and a method should look like this: `void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }`

Comment: :) , i'm using a wimform component , it's Z-order is always higher 
and would occur before  mouseup routed event handler.
with this new information , can i re ask the above question?

Comment: Winforms component in WPF? Every time I was using Windows Forms Host it was pain because of airspace issue, some events weren't received at all. Anyway you better ask a separate question, it becomes hard for me to realize what you need without some code :)